# In SAS, how do I save my newly created columns in a table?

Tags: sas

I am new to programming in SAS. I have a table called cohort_sc with the column MRN stored as a character with leading zeros. To remove the leading zeros I cast it into an int and back to a character. But, when I run any other code after this, the two new columns mrn_int and mrn_char are no longer stored in cohort_sc.  How can I save the new columns?

```
data cohort_sc;
set cohort_sc;
MRN_INT = INPUT(MRN,best.); 
MRN_char = PUT(MRN_INT,12.); 
set cohort_sc;
run;
```

Comment: Why do you have two SET statements?  Why are you using the same name for the output dataset as the input dataset?

Comment: because I don't know what I'm doing. I already have a database called cohort_sc, I just want to add 2 new columns

Comment: What errors, warnings or notes do you get in the SAS log when you run that data step?

Comment: I don't get any errors, warnings or notes. what happens is I can view the data with the new columns, but after I run more code, I can only view the original 3 columns, the new ones are gone. EDIT: I guess I get the following notes: " NOTE: There were 9776 observations read from the data set WORK.COHORT_SC.
 NOTE: There were 9776 observations read from the data set WORK.COHORT_SC.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.COHORT_SC has 9776 observations and 5 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.01 seconds
    ..."

Comment: So the data step worked.  Remember that WORK datasets disappear when your current SAS session ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite your existing dataset. that will make it hard to debug when you make mistakes as you will have to recreate the original dataset to try again.

Your code should work, but you might want to make sure that the new variables are defined as you want instead of forcing SAS to GUESS how you want to define them.

Note that `BEST` is the name of a FORMAT, not an INFORMAT. The INPUT() function does not care if the width of the informat is more than the length of the string you are reading, so just use `32.` as then informat as that is the maximum number of characters it can read.

The `12.` format will right align the digit strings.  Do you really want leading spaces in your new MRN_CHAR variable?

```
data new_cohort_sc;
  set cohort_sc;
  length MRN_INT 8 MRN_char $12 ;
  MRN_INT = INPUT(MRN,32.); 
  MRN_char = left(PUT(MRN_INT,12.)); 
run;
```

You could do it without making the numeric value by using the VERIFY() function to find the location of the first character that is not a '0' in your existing MRN variable.

```
data new_cohort_sc;
  set cohort_sc;
  length MRN_char $12 ;
  MRN_char = substr(MRN,max(1,verify(MRN,'0')));
run;
```

Comment: thanks. regarding the leading spaces, can i have it adjust to the number of characters, for example if one of the is "123" and the other is "12", how can i store them wihtout leading spaces?

Comment: Character variables are fixed length.  You just need to define it for the maximum possible length.  The LEFT() function removes leading spaces.  You could also just append the -L modifier to the format used in the PUT() function.  `put(mrn_int,12.-L)`